# Sidebar slides in and out on page refresh

Tags: css, react-hooks, create-react-app

I created a sidebar (hidden by default) in a web store that contains a list of items you like. When clicked on a button the likes-list will show sliding in from the right smoothly. However on page refresh/reload the sidebar slides in and out rapidly. I'm using css animation to do the trick.
It works fine but somehow on page reload the animation is triggered without clicking the button. How to prevent this from happening?
App is built in React (create-react-app).

### React component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../Context'
import './likes.css';

const Likes = ({ showLikes, setShowLikes }) => {

    let { liked, setLiked, paintings, setPaintings } = useGlobalContext()

    //Remove item from likes list
    const removeItemFromLikeslist = (id) => {
        liked = liked.filter(item => {
            return item.id !== id;
        });

        //Change likes-heart to green
        paintings = paintings.map(el => {
            if (el.id === id) {
                el.like = false
            }
            return el
        })

        //remove sidebar overlay
        if (liked.length === 0) {
            setShowLikes(false)
        }

        setPaintings(paintings)
        setLiked(liked)
        localStorage.setItem("PAINTINGS", JSON.stringify(paintings))
        localStorage.setItem('LIKES', JSON.stringify(liked))
    }


return (

    <div className={showLikes ? "likesContainer show" : "likesContainer"} >
            <div className="likesHeader">You like these paintings</div>
            {liked.map(item => {
                const { id, name, imgSrc } = item;
                return (
                    <div className="like-item" onClick={() => removeItemFromLikeslist(id)} key={id}>
                        <div className="like-info">
                            <img src={imgSrc} style={{ width: "100px" }} alt={name} className="picInCart" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="like-name">
                            <h5>{name}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Likes
```

### CSS file

```
   .likesContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 83px;
    right: -328px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
    height:auto; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px black;
    animation: animateHide .5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animateHide {
   from {
     right: 0;
   }
   to {
      right: -328px;
   }
}

.likesContainer.show {
    right: 0;
    animation: animateShow .5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animateShow {
   from {
     right: -328px;
   }
   to {
      right: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Animations are triggered with `animation` attribute only but you can add a separate class which is added on click of button

Comment: Thanks Rana, I got rid of the animation attribute and using the transition property. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, changed from animation to transition like so:

```
   .likesContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 83px;
    right: -328px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
    height:auto; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px black;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  }

.likesContainer.show {
     right: 0;
  }
```